# Probability that $N$ persons all have flipped heads in $t$ flips

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm trying to learn a little probability by myself since it never was my strongest field, but I encountered a problem I could not solve, so I thought I'd ask.

Let there be $N>2$ persons each with identical biased coins that land heads with probability $p$ (and tails with $1-p$). In each trial every person flips their coin and if they land head, they are eliminated from future trials.

The question is then:

> What is the probability that after $t-1$ trials there are exactly $2$ persons left, and that in the $t$'th trial these both are eliminated? (i.e. no persons left after $t$ trials)

I can calculate the probability that not all are  eliminated in trial number $t-1$ and then eliminated in the next, but I don't know how I can extend this to the fact that exactly $2$ are left.

Comment: Hint: choose the two survivors, $\binom N2$ ways to do it.  Those two tossed $T$ every time, easy to get the probability.  The others got at least one $H$ (get the probability by subtraction).

Comment: @lulu I'm trying to follow your hints, but I cannot quite get something I think is correct. The probability of tossing $T$ every time in the $t-1$ trials should be $(1-p)^{t-1}$, correct? So are you saying
$${N\choose 2}(1-p)^{t-1}$$
for the first term? I think it cannot be correct because it is larger than $1$ for certain parameter values. The probability of at least one head should be $1-(1-p)^{t-1}$. Can you give another hint?

Comment: Let $q=(1-p)^{t-1}$.  Then $q$ is the probability that a given player survives.  The probability that two given players survive is then $q^2$.

Comment: Think of this as a disguised Bernoulli process.  A given player either survives or not.  Survival has probability $q=(1-p)^{t-1}$.  Non-survival has probability $1-q$.  So your setup for the first $t-1$ tosses is just "flip N coins one time, each of which comes up H with probability $q$.  What is the probability that you get exactly $2$ H's?"

Comment: I think I get something that makes sense for the first part with the help of your hints. Does it make sense to say that the probability is
$${N\choose 2}q^2(1-q)^{N-2} $$
that there are exactly $2$ players left after $t-1$ trials?

Comment: That's exactly right.

Comment: Note:  the site gets unhappy if questions are left unanswered.  If you are so inclined, write up the complete solution and post it.  Your call.

Comment: @lulu Thank you for your help, and so the probability that $2$ persons are eliminated is $p^2$ so the probability of my full question is

$$p^2{N\choose 2}q^2(1-q)^{N-2}. $$

If you want the reputation that you rightly deserve, you can write an answer :). Otherwise I will write one soon.

Comment: I agree with the answer.  Go ahead and write up the solution yourself, but thanks for the offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that a player gets $T$ in all $t-1$ trials is $q:=(1-p)^{t-1}.$ The probability that a player gets at least one $H$ is $1-q$. There are ${N\choose 2}$ ways to choose the $2$ remaining players out of $N$ total players.

The probability that there are exactly $2$ players left after $t-1$ trials is then
$${N\choose 2} q^2(1-q)^{N-2}.$$

The probability that the remaining players flip heads in the next row is $p^2$, hence the final answer is

$$p^2{N\choose 2} q^2(1-q)^{N-2}. $$